# como puedo hacer para que haga cambio de pagina depende del radiobutton que se escoja?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

lo que necesito es que en mi programa, estoy buscando la manera que por medio de radio botones haga una seleccion de archivos, cada selecion tiene su propio formulario, ya estuve buscando por jquery, por medio de javascript, y hasta el momento no encuentro, de hecho lo que ya realiza mi programa que la seleccion la manda al url de la pagina principal pero ahi es donde no paso porque no elige ningun link, o ruta de especificacion...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/log.js"> 
  <title>Enlace</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <div align="center" ></div>
          <div class="login">Informacion Trabajo o Estudio</div>
          <div class="eula">Seguimiento a Egresados</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">       
            <div class="form">
                <form name="radio" action="#">
                  <div class="radiogroup" >          
                    <h4 style=" margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Despues de Terminar tu Preparacion te Dedicaste a: </h4>
                        <div class="wrapper">                         
                            <input class="state" type="radio" name="saliendo" id="trabajar" value="trabajar" required>
                            <label class="label" for="trabajar">
                            <div class="indicator"></div>
                            <span class="text">a)Trabajar</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input class="state" type="radio" name="saliendo" id="estudiar" value="estudiar" required> 
                            <label class="label" for="estudiar">
                            <div class="indicator"></div>
                            <span class="text">b)Estudiar</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input class="state" type="radio" name="saliendo" id="ambos" value="ambos" required>
                            <label class="label" for="ambos">
                            <div class="indicator"></div>
                            <span class="text">c)Ambos</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <input class="state" type="radio" name="saliendo" id="ninguno" value="ninguno" required>
                            <label class="label" for="ninguno">
                            <div class="indicator"></div>
                            <span class="text">d)Ninguna</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Siguiente" style="padding: 0%;" onclick="dispaly()">
                            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Borrar" style="padding: 0%; margin-top:0;">       
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veo que el botón submit invoca la función dispaly()  ¿no será display()?. De todas maneras  son el código Javascript no se puede ver más a fondo el problema.

Comment: gracias por la observacion, pero no es esa tuve que quitar un poco de codigo... que tenia yo en java porque no me dejaba subirlo,, la pagina, pero volviendo a lo mismo, lo que busco es que por medio de la seleccion de un radio boton, cuando yo de la opcion submit, este lea que valor y me redireccione a una pagina... distinta a la que tengo...

Comment: Eso lo debe hacer la función display(), debe leer el valor del radio-button y elegir la url que le corresponda. Es que no se lo que hace display(), por eso te decía que sin el  código Javascript poco más se puede decir.

Comment: ok entiendo, tu que harias o que tipo de codigo ingresarias en la parte de js.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues yo haría lo siguiente con la función display() que se dispara al pulsar el botón de submit:

```
  function display()
  {
  event.preventDefault();
  /*con jQuery
  var opcion = $("input[name='saliendo']:checked").val();
  */
  var opcion = event.target.parentElement.saliendo.value
  switch (opcion){
      case "trabajar":
        window.location.href= "url trabajar"
        break;
      case "estudiar":
        window.location.href= "url estudiar"
        break;
      case "ambos":
        window.location.href= "url ambos"
        break;
      case "ninguno":
        window.location.href= "url ninguno"
        break;
    }
  }
```

Con preventDefault evitas que actúe el submit de form. En función del valor del botón vas a una url. He usado switch case para seleccionar la url.
Puedes usar jQuery o Javascript puro

Comment: super, de hecho en uno de mis tantas pruebas lo habia intentado por ello estaba aun el display, solo que no redireccionaba me faltaba eso... mil gracias